# Windows Crypto API support OCSP

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, cryptoapi

Does .net Crypto API support OCSP certificate validation or should I look at Bouncy Castle for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a quick search shows that [Crypto API supports OCSP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee619754%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23103438/cms-encryption-decryption-using-crypto-api-how-to-specify-algorithmidentifier not found